# x for x in mylist if x not in myNames - for letter

Tags: python, list

Hello I have this code:

```
import pandas as pd

failas = 'test.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(failas)
df2 = df.drop_duplicates()
mylist = df2['EMAILS'].tolist()

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
myNames = f.read().splitlines()


Output = []

Output = [x for x in mylist if x not in myNames]

# Printing Output
print("Intial list is :", mylist)
print("Delete list :", myNames)
print("List after removing elements is :", Output)
```

I want to remove from mylist all the elements that is in myNames. in example element 'tr' should remove all the elements that has 'tr' like: 'trys', '55tr234', and 'tr' itself.

Comment: can you be more clear? 'tr' is in the my_names list or my_list?

Comment: Hello Skander, sorry I am noob here :). So I have the list 'mylist; in excel file: EMAILS
trys
dutrys
trys4
14trys
bbc , and I have list named 'myNames' in txt file: tr
vie
5
8
u,  I want to remove the myNames elements from mylist. In example if in myNames ihave 'tr' that should remove all the elements from 'mylist' that has that part 'tr'.

Comment: Please **update your question** with the contents (or sample contents) of the two lists.  This will help us debug with real data.  Additionally, have a look into list comprehension with a regex filter.

Comment: in example: list1 = ['vienas', 'du', 'trys5'],  and list2 = ['na','5']. I want to remove the list2 elements that has that part of list2 also repeated ones, from list1 so list3 would be ['du']. Hope that is more clear now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check that all the elements in `myNames` are not within a `mylist` element.

```
mylist = ['vienas', 'du', 'trys5']
myNames = ['na','5']

output = [x for x in mylist if all(y not in x for y in myNames)]
# output = ['du']
```